# Cover block always has margin

Tags: pages, design

I'm working on a website where I want to have some group blocks where I want to add some images of patterns to just make the website a bit nicer than just plain colors. I'm using a cover block to hold the image and have content on top of it. I want to have the cover cover the whole group block it is in but there is margins on both sides on the group. In the example below it's the light blue parts:

[image]

Here is the structure for this group:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: this isn't something that can be fixed from a screenshot, opening the site in a browser with dev tools is necessary, though as far as I can tell group blocks that have a background colour will have padding, I don't see why the cover block can't do the job that the group block is doing though

Comment: I see, just using the cover works great! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the cover block instead, the group block isn't necessary, and will have padding if it's given a background colour.